# Navigate through Controls and Components

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to traverse all controls and components inside a UserControl I'm developing.
I tried:

```
public void Traverse(Control cnt)
{
    foreach (Control c in cnt.Controls)
    {
        if (c.HasChildren) Traverse(c);
        Debug.Print(c.Name); // For debugging purpose only
        // My code goes here
    }
}
```

Problem raises when functions meets a **ToolStrip**: it has no children, but Items (`ToolStripItemCollection: IList, ICollection, IEnumerable`).

I don't care of type: using Reflection I need to set some property, so I feel good having objects as result.
How can I get the name of every component that is inside my UserControl?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should check `if(c is IEnumerable)` and enumerate contained objects

Comment: @L.B: doesn't help: when you traverse UserControl and find a ToolStrip, you can't use foreach if don't hard-write `in ts.Items`... and I don't want to write code for every possible subitem I have in my control (well, if possible)

Comment: @Marco - I removed my answer. In order to go through the control in a "generic" manner and see if there's IEnumerables, etc. it ended up involving reflection.

Comment: The ToolStripItem classes don't derive from Control.  Clearly you cannot traverse them with the method signature you have now.  Do something different if (c is ToolStrip).

Comment: yes @HansPassant, I know. But I was searching a way to traverse every single _object_ contained in my UserControl without using _if_ or _case_ (because if I insert a new kind of object I have to set another _if_ and it's dangerous because I'm going to forget one, I know). I'm going to check CAbbott's answer, because it seems the right one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a version that goes through the control's properties and looks for `IComponent`s that have `ICollection`s on them:

**Method:**

```
private void GetControls(ICollection controls, IList<string> names)
{
    foreach (var ctl in controls)
    {
        if (ctl is IComponent)
        {
            var name = ctl.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
            if (name != null)
                names.Add((string) name.GetValue(ctl, null));

            foreach (var property in ctl.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var prop = property.GetValue(ctl, null);
                if (prop is ICollection)
                    GetControls((ICollection)prop, names);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Called:**

```
var ctlNames = new List<string>();
GetControls(Controls, ctlNames);
```

I've tested this and it seems to find every control on the form. I haven't tested it for every kind of control and I can't vouch for how efficient it is.

Comment: It's not efficient, but it's not your fault. Anyway your answer is what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yeah, there may be ways of tightening up the list of properties that it looks at. Glad it worked out for you.